# How to centre-align a title above few image?

Tags: html, css

[image: my desire outcome]

my relative html code now is like this. I haven't add the title in the below code yet. Please help. Thank you.

```
<div class="body">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Main.</h1>
            <h3>type something</h2>
            <section class="buttonone">
                <button>Sign up</button>
            </section>  
        </div>
        <section class="container">
            <figure>
            <div class="random"><img src="drink.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <figcaption>lemonade</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
            <div class="random"><img src="toro.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <figcaption>omakasa-Toro sushi</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
            <div class="random"><img src="noodle.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <figcaption>ramei</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
            <div class="random"><img src="oyster.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <figcaption>oyster sushi</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
```

Comment: what is your desired output?? Provided code is not enough for debugging your problem.

Comment: Please add also your css

Comment: https://cdn.statically.io/gh/TheOdinProject/curriculum/main/foundations/html_css/project/odin-project.png 

This is the desire outcome. I am struggling on the "Some random information part" . I just can't put those word right above the images.

Answer (score 1):

use flexbox

```css
img {
  width: 10vw;
  }
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#title{
text-align:center;
border:solid 1px black;
}

figure{
border:solid 1px black;
padding:6px;
}
```

```html
  <div id='title'>my Title</div>
  <section class="container">
    <figure>
      <div class="random"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
      <figcaption>lemon</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <div class="random"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
      <figcaption>omaka</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <div class="random"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
      <figcaption>ramei</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <div class="random"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
      <figcaption>oysteri</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
```

Comment: I tried. But the outcome is "title" being on the left side of those pics.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox?retiredLocale=it) to your CSS code! with [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

I also used [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for centering vertically easily using the new [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) css property

[image]

```css
.container {
    /* make items one near the other in the X axis */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
    /* if the image is a lot bigger, it will be resized and be responsive */
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* centering vertically */
.container>figure,
.intro {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>Main.</h1>
    <h3>type something</h2>
      <section class="buttonone">
        <button>Sign up</button>
      </section>
  </div>
  <section class="container">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <figure>
      <div class="random">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
      </div>
      <figcaption>lemonade</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <!-- 2 -->
    <figure>
      <div class="random">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
      </div>
      <figcaption>omakasa-Toro sushi</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <!-- 3 -->
    <figure>
      <div class="random">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
      </div>
      <figcaption>ramei</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <!-- 4 -->
    <figure>
      <div class="random">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
      </div>
      <figcaption>oyster sushi</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s a start, but the title is not centred, as requested in the question. Why don’t you add `justify-items` to your code instead of at the end as a quote?

Comment: ok @Andy  I will do it now

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent container `class=container` and make two child containers `class=text centre` for center aligned text and `class=img grid` for the image grid.

Now your parent container class will be having `display: flex` property with `flex-grow or width` property now for text you'll be putting `text-align: center` and for grid class you'll be using `justify-content: space-between`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to add css `h1 {text-align: center;}`

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <section class="container">

            <figure>
                <div class="random">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1076/201/201.jpg?hmac=w0KXxl0av8l5EHqgJfjULxPosXBvFTV86-fnAGgZbnY" alt="">
                </div>
            </figure>

            <figure>
                <div class="random">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1076/201/201.jpg?hmac=w0KXxl0av8l5EHqgJfjULxPosXBvFTV86-fnAGgZbnY" alt="">
                </div>
            </figure>

            <figure>
                <div class="random">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1076/201/201.jpg?hmac=w0KXxl0av8l5EHqgJfjULxPosXBvFTV86-fnAGgZbnY" alt="">
                </div>
            </figure>

            <figure>
                <div class="random">
                    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1076/201/201.jpg?hmac=w0KXxl0av8l5EHqgJfjULxPosXBvFTV86-fnAGgZbnY" alt="">
                </div>
            </figure>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex; justify-content: center;` and make sure you have a width of a 100% and those CSS properties will work almost everywhere.

[image: screenshot]

```Html
<div class="body">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Main.</h1>
        <h3>type something</h2>
        <section class="buttonone">
            <button>Sign up</button>
        </section>  
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    <section class="container">
        <figure>
        <div class="random">
            <img src="./pexels-till-daling-12461880.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <figcaption>lemonade</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
        <div class="random">
            <img src="./pexels-till-daling-12461880.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <figcaption>omakasa-Toro sushi</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
        <div class="random">
            <img src="./pexels-till-daling-12461880.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <figcaption>ramei</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
        <div class="random">
            <img src="./pexels-till-daling-12461880.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <figcaption>oyster sushi</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
</div>
```

```CSS
    .title {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    img {
        width: 10rem;
        height: 10rem;
    }
```